# Tmux list windows remap move up/down

Tags: tmux

I am using a bépo keyboard layout. Tmux has a nice feature to list windows and let the user choose which one to open using `j` and `k` keys. As these keys are not really handy with bépo, I would like to remap them to `t` and `s`.

Is there a way to remap them?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now (tmux 2.3), there is no way to remap j and k through the `tmux.conf` file. You could clone the tmux git repo, modify the [key bindings](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/895f1d93d51f54b3f76e6406d51f4fc491399ce2/mode-key.c#L332), and rebuild the executable from source (look at the tmux github main page for instructions on this)

Comment: Thank you. Not really handy though. Hope to see that feature appear someday.

Comment: If you'd like to see the feature, send a feature suggestion email to the [tmux-users google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tmux-users)